# Split english text into senteces(multiple lines)

Tags: c++, string, text

I wondering about an efficient way to split text into sentences.
Sentences are split by a dot + space

Example text

```
 The quick brown fox jumps 
 over the lazy dog. I love eating toasted cheese and tuna sandwiches.
```

My algorithm works like this

```
Read first line from text file to string
Find what is needed
Write to file
```

However sometimes half of a sentence can be on a upcoming line.

So I was wondering what is the best way to confront this problem

Yes a tried googling "search across multiple lines" and I don't want to use regex

Initially my idea is to check if the first line ends with a `.+ space` and if not grab another line and search through it. But I have a feeling I am missing out on something.

EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention that I am doing this in C++

Comment: Maybe the [`BreakIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) can be of help? " Sentence boundary analysis allows selection with correct interpretation of periods within numbers and abbreviations, and trailing punctuation marks such as quotation marks and parentheses. "

Comment: What is wrong about your initial idea? That should work.

Comment: Don't read line-by-line, read each character individually and eat the carriage returns `\r` and new lines `\n`.  Keep a std::string for your current work 'stack' and pop the stack when you see a period (or `eof`).

Comment: Can't you just load the whole text into memory and do a text search for `'.'` followed by a *whitespace*?

Comment: Are you sure the line ends in `.+space` and not `.+newline`?  I would start by reading words `stream >> word` and then check the last pos of each word for `'.'`. That way the `>>` will handle whitespace other than the space character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like accumulator.

```
1. Read line
2. Check the last symbols in this line.
3. If last symbols are dot or dot+space
 3.1 Split it and write all strings to output 
 3.2 GOTO 1
ELSE 
  3.3 split the line, write length-1 strings to output
  3.4 Keep last piece in some variable and append next readed line to it.
```

Hope my idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach for this problem

```
void to_sentences()
{
    // Do not skip whitespaces
    std::cin >> std::noskipws;

    char c;
    // Loop until there is no input
    while (std::cin >> c) {
        // Skip new lines
        if (c == '\n')
            continue;

        // Output the character
        std::cout << c;

        // check if there is a dot folowed by space
        // if there add new line
        if (c == '.') {
            std::cin >> c;
            if (c == ' ')
                std::cout << endl;
        }
    }

    // Reset skip whitespaces
    std::cin >> std::skipws;
}
```

You can read the comments and ask if there is something unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::getline()`, with custom **delimeter** '.'

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto split_to_sentences(std::string inp)
{
    std::istringstream ss(inp); // make a stream using the string
    std::vector< std::string > sentences; // return value

    while(true) {
        std::string this_sentence;

        std::getline(ss, this_sentence, '.');
        if (this_sentence != "") 
            sentences.push_back(std::move(this_sentence));
        else 
            return sentences;
    }
}
```

Note that if you have the input text as a **stream**, then you can skip the `std::stringstream` step, and give the stream directly to `std::getline`, in the place of `ss`.

The use of `std::move` is not necessary, but might increase performance, by preventing a copy and a deletion of the dynamic parts (on heap) of `std::string`.

Comment: In my opinion, The problem with this approach is that it doesn't handle new lines. so I think you need to find a way to handle it.